# Comparing id sender to instance pointer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, comparison

How do I compare the `id` argument to an `IBAction`, to a instance pointer?

```
IBOutlet UITextField * tw1;
IBOutlet UITextField * tw2;
```

the `==` doesn't look to work:

```
- (IBAction) editingDidEnd:(id) sender 
{

    if (sender == tw1) {
       ...
    }
    if (sender == two) {
       ...
    }
}
```

`id` is something like `(void*)`, so the comparison of these two pointers should yield true, because both point to the same spot, but it doesn't.

Comment: Double-check that the outlets and the actions are hooked up. Your code is correct.

Comment: Alternatively, set the tag property to an enum or similar. :)

Comment: @onnoweb bad idea. The code is correct.

Comment: @onnoweb: That isn't valid syntax.

Comment: You can change the (id) to (UITextField *) in the IBAction method, it's not obligatory.

Comment: Yeah, was a little too quick with the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line: `(sender == two)`, "two" is not "tw2". If that's not a typo in your question, it's a bug in your program.

If the typo isn't the problem, something probably isn't connected the way you think it is. Add these lines to see what's going on:

```
NSLog(@"sender: %p, tw1: %p, tw2: %p", sender, tw1, tw2); //changed %x to %p
NSLog(@"sender == tw1: %d", sender == tw1);
NSLog(@"sender == tw2: %d", sender == tw2);
```

If tw1 and tw2 are 0, you don't have them connected in Interface Builder.

Comment: Well-spotted on the typo. Use `%p` to print addresses. You could also use the object specifier: `%@`. Then they will print as `(null)` if not connected.

Comment: Thanks, I had never used %p before. That will correctly scale for a 64-bit program. I'm still writing 32-bit programs at work. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison is ok, but the reason I am not sure is that I wouldn't have coded it that way.  Why not have two actions, and then you'll know for sure which one fired?

Comparing pointers just seems wrong.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid and common thing to do; checking which control sent the message is one of the reasons that the control is passed along in the first place.